# How to skip first line of questions in quiz in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to skip a first line in question. Here is a part of my code:

```
 newques="n"
    while newques=="n":
          file=open("questions.txt","r")
          found=False
          for line in file:
              split=line.split(",")
              question=split[0]
              options=split[1]
              correct=split[2]
              found=True
          file.close()
          if found==True:
              print(question)
              print(options)
              answer=input("Enter correct letter")
              if answer==correct:
                  print("Correct!")
              else:
                  print("Incorrect!")
          newques=input("next question press n")
```

Questions are in a txt file formatted like the following:

```
1)Who is Beyonce married to?,A = Skengdo   B = Jay Z,B
2)Who performed Bodak Yellow?,A = Cardi B   B =Kodak Black,A
```

Comment: Ok, so this is what your code is doing: You are opening questions.txt, iterate over every line and store only the last in your variables. Then ask the user for input and start the process again.
What - I guess - you need to do, is to read the file. Store it in an array and access that array from within your `while newques=="n"` loop.

Comment: I don't understand; could you give an example?

Comment: Why do you want to skip the first line?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your questions.txt is such as every question starts in a new line. You read in the file into an array (questions). Then you access that array from inside your loop and advance one question each time (q).

```
newques="n"
file=open("questions.txt","r")
questions = [line for line in file]

q = 0 # current question
while newques=="n":
      split=questions[q].split(",")
      question=split[0]
      options=split[1]
      correct=split[2].strip() # delete \n newline
      print(question)
      print(options)
      answer=input("Enter correct letter")
      if answer==correct:
          print("Correct!")
      else:
          print("Incorrect!")
      q += 1
      newques=input("next question press n")
```